# Dagger 2 Scope Lifetimes

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am currently acquainting myself with dagger2 and dependency injection in general. I think I have a decent grasp of the basics, but I am having trouble understanding scopes. There are two things I would like some help understanding. A) about scope lifetimes, and B) about reuse of scopes multiple times.

When speaking of scopes, the idea of the lifetime of the scope invariably comes up.I gather that for dependencies provided under a given scope a single instance will be provided while that scope is "alive". What actually determines if a scope is alive or dead? is it tied to the lifetime of the component that is annotated with it? if that component goes out of scope and is GC'd then is that the death of that scope?

Also a related question: Say I have some dependencies that i want to scope to one of two activities. Do I need to create two separate scopes (ie `@MainActivityScope` and `@SettingsActivityScope`), or can I use a generic activity scope (`@ActivityScope`) that I use for both but which denotes two separate scopes depending on how it is used? Perhaps when I understand my first question, that will help me understand the answer to this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977472/dagger-component-dependency-meaning/42977627#42977627) answer

Comment: @azizbekian Sorry, the linked answer is not exactly clear to me. I am still responsible for nulling out dependencies that are done with? Isnt that something dagger handles? isnt that the point of scopes? to handle that?

Comment: Dagger cannot guess when you are done with a particular scope. You should manually null out the scope, so that the next time a fresh dependency would be provided.

Answer (score 6):

Dagger handles scopes in the most simple way possible: A scope belongs to a Component *instance*. If you have a scoped binding, it is stored in and retrieved from the Component instance with the matching scope.

```
@Singleton @Component(...) public interface MyComponent {
  ActivityComponent createActivityComponent(); // creates a new ActivityComponent

  Thing1 getThing1();  // @Singleton

  Thing2 getThing2();  // no scope
}

@ActivityScope @Subcomponent(...) public interface ActivityComponent {
  Thing3 getThing3();  // @ActivityScoped

  Thing4 getThing4();  // no scope
}
```

The concept of "living or dead" isn't really relevant here. What matters is that through each ActivityComponent you create, you get a different instance of Thing3, but the same instance of Thing1. If you create a new ActivityComponent instance for each activity you create, then when the activity is destroyed, the Component will (ideally) become unreachable and be collected. However, as far as Dagger is concerned, you can create as many ActivityComponents as you'd like and have them coexist.

```
MyComponent myComponent = DaggerMyComponent.create();
Thing1 a = myComponent.getThing1();
Thing1 b = myComponent.getThing1();  //  b == a
Thing2 c = myComponent.getThing2();
Thing2 d = myComponent.getThing2();  //  c != d
```

Unscoped means new instance per injection. Now let's try the subcomponent:

```
ActivityComponent activityComponent1 = myComponent.createActivityComponent();
Thing3 e = activityComponent1.getThing3();
Thing3 f = activityComponent1.getThing3();  //  e == f
ActivityComponent activityComponent2 = myComponent.createActivityComponent();
Thing3 g = activityComponent2.getThing3();  //  e != g

// But you can still use activityComponent1. It's not dead.
Thing3 h = activityComponent1.getThing3();  //  e == h
```

Naturally, this also propagates through the graph: If Thing2 depends on Thing1, you might have many Thing2 instances which each depend on a common singleton Thing1 instance. If Thing4 were to depend on Thing1, Thing2, and Thing3, then you might have many Thing4 instances, each with their own Thing2, with Thing3 shared within the same activity (component) and Thing1 shared within the same overall (application/singleton) component.

As long as they're all parts of separate hierarchies, you can have as many ActivityComponents as you'd like, or as many @ActivityScoped components. You might choose to make an @ActivityScoped MainActivityComponent and an @ActivityScoped SettingsActivityComponent, or make a single common ActivityComponent that knows how to inject each. You probably don't need a @MainActivityScope and a @SettingsActivityScope, because one won't ever derive from the other. The important thing is that you create a new @ActivityScoped component *instance* per *activity instance*, which is all Dagger needs to keep the scopes aligned.

Comment: Can you explain for me why should I create "new custom scope" instead of using Singleton scope and no-scope. Basically I see that singleton scope is same as custom scope.

Comment: If I understand correctly, scope is using for sub-module. So when we inject an object X from submodule A < module B. we will know life-time of X is bounded to submodule A or B right ?

Comment: @hqt Singleton scope and no-scope are the most common, and you can often get by without any custom scopes. Good examples of custom scopes are per Request or Session (web) or per Activity or Fragment (android). Those are opportunities for Dagger to encapsulate your object creation logic, rather than creating a custom filter for "should I create a new object for context object instance X" (where context might be Request/Session/Activity/Fragment/etc).